# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed expo node backend

Tags: android, react-native, fetch, expo

I have a node backend that my expo app is querying. The node-express-mongo backend works just perfect which I can verify using GET Request from Postman but I get unhandled promise rejection Network Failed error in my app

**Complete error:**

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
- node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:473:29 in xhr.onerror
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

here's my code:

**api.js**

```
export const fetchMeetups = () =>
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/meetups')
        .then(res => res.json());
```

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { fetchMeetups } from './constants/api'; 

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: `Press Cmd+R to reload,\nCmd+D or shake for dev menu`,
  android: `Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\nShake or press menu button for dev menu`,
});


class App extends React.Component{
  static defaultProps = {
    fetchMeetups
  }

  state = {
    loading: false,
    meetups: []

  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({loading: true});
    const data = await this.props.fetchMeetups();
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({loading: false, meetups: data.meetups}),2000)
  }


  render(){
    if(this.state.loading){
      return(
        <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>MeetupME</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

**index.js**

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

--------------UPDATE------------------
added a catch block to fetch & getting this new error

```
Network request failed
- node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:473:29 in xhr.onerror
- node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

[image: emulator]

[image: postman]

Answer (score 17):

Had the same issue with React-native Expo and Python Django back-end.
The problem is about a conflict between an emulator localhost and server localhost.
Your back-end-server might be ruunning on 127.0.0.1:8000, but an emulator can't find this.

In terminal find your Ipv4-Address with a command 'ipconfig'.
**For ex., it will be 192.138.1.40**

After this put it in your fetch (
'http://192.138.1.40:8000/').
And what is also important - **run your back-end-server with the same host and port.**
On python Django for example:

> py manage.py runserver 192.138.1.40:8000

On Django you will also need to add ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.138.1.40'] in settings.py

Answer (score 1):

in place of localhost in your url, http://localhost:3000/api/meetups, give your ip address, like http://192.168.49.108:3000/api/meetups

Comment: that didn't work. The localhost:3000/api/meetups is node process

Comment: also now in browser...this address doesn't return me json...I still get unresolved promise error in expo emulator app

Comment: run this in terminal - adb reverse tcp:8163 tcp:8163 and try

Comment: no  didn't help...I think there's some problem with fetch...because it's not getting json object from fetch....it should fetch from localhost:3000/api/meetups ....like incase of postman

Comment: when I make localhost:3000/api/meetups get request ...it return me json in browser as well...so I think it's working at backend part....also the react part is also right...the only part that's not working .... const data = await this.props.fetchMeetups();

Comment: I have updated my question with catch block on fetch....you see the error....the problem is with fetchMeetups

Comment: Try to call fetch in your App.js, it will be easy to debug. Try fetch with proper error handling,
check these examples here - https://reactnative.dev/docs/network

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of reading about this issue I found this to be an bug in Expo

To go back I cleared the Expo cache on Android
[image]